# Html-to-image in NextJS not working properly, downloaded the same reference

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I've been having some trouble with `html-to-image` library, inside a Next.js project.
This is the code I used for converting image with `html-to-image`

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import {toPng} from 'html-to-image'

const divReferenceA = useRef(null);
const divReferenceB = useRef(null);
const [type, setType] = useState(true)

const convertDivToPng = async div => {
    const data = await toPng(div, {
      cacheBust: true,
      canvasWidth: 842,
      canvasHeight: 595,
    });
    return data;
  };

const handleDownloadA = async e => {
    try {
      const data = await convertDivToPng(divReferenceA.current);
      if (data) {
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = data;
        link.download = "Image A.png";
        link.click();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, "ini error sertifikat");
    }
  };

const handleDownloadB = async e => {
    try {
      const data = await convertDivToPng(divReferenceB.current);
      if (data) {
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = data;
        link.download = "Image B.png";
        link.click();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, "ini errornya");
    }
  };

return (
    <div ref={divReferenceA}> {... content with <Image /> from next-image }</div>
    <button onClick={e => handleDownloadA(e)}>
        Download
    </button>
    {type == true ? (
        <div className="position-relative p-0 d-flex" ref={divReferenceB}> 
            {... content with <Image /> from next-image but different image from refA }</div>
        <button onClick={e => handleDownloadB(e)}>
            Download
        </button>
    ) : <div> </div>
```

My problem is when I load the page and I click download button for the `divRefferenceA`, I will successfully convert and download the whole div. However, when I clicked download button for `divRefferenceB` after, I will download the div of the `divRefferenceA` again. But when I `console.log(divRefferenceB.current)` it shows the `divRefferenceB` as expected.

So I reload the page again, I press the `divRefferenceB` download button, I will successfully convert and download the whole div of `divRefferenceB`, but after I press download button for the `divRefferenceA`, I will download the `divRefferenceB`. So I'm guessing that every time I download something for the first time, the `dataURL` will stick around unless I reload the pages. Not sure wha'ts happening.

However, I experiment something. I created another div inside my pages:

```js
const testRef = useRef(null)

const handleDownloadTest = async e => {
    try {
      const data = await convertDivToPng(testRef.current);
      if (data) {
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = data;
        link.download = "Image B.png";
        link.click();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, "ini errornya");
    }
};

<div ref={testRef}>
   <div>a</div>
   <div>a</div>
   <div>a</div>
</div>
```

The problem doesn't happen when I download this div and worked as expected. I'm so confused. Is there any problem with nextImage? I'm not sure what's happening. Been trying this and that for 2 days, but can't fix the problem.

**===================PROBLEM SOLVED!===================**

its turned out that i haved some problems with cors that were not set within the backend environment that i did not aware of.
the reason i found this error is that i tried to directly fetch the image using

```
const data = await axios.get('s3-bucket-api')
if(data){
  console.log(data)
}
```

then i got error response about the cors related problem.
later on we tried to tweak the backend environment and the problem were solved

Comment: Post the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question, do not add it to the question.

Comment: I am experiencing the same. How did you manage to solve this? Is this a backend error? I am using Nextjs 13

Answer (score 0):

please check

```
  const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.